# Is it possible to split a NOTAM in two messages in case it is too long to fit in a single message?

Tags: notam, icao-sarps, aim

Would it be in accordance with ICAO norms to issue two different NOTAMs with the same year, series and number regarding the same subject and informing //PART 1 OF 2 PARTS// and //PART 2 OF 2 PARTS// in the NOTAMs bodies to inform that they are parts of a single NOTAM?

Comment: Have you considered that a NOTAM might not be the best choice for promulgating such a lengthy tome?  Perhaps editing for brevity may be the answer here, or reconsidering if it is worthwhile to feed to hapless airmen the world over?

Comment: I understand that a NOTAM should not be that long and that it should be edited for brevity. Still, I would like to know if it would be in accordance with ICAO norms to issue two NOTAMs with same year, series and number if they refer to the same subject.

Comment: I have seen it done before but i forgot where.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multi-part NOTAMs seem to be part of ICAO standard, as far as googling reveals. I can’t seem to find a definitive reference though.

An example - and from experience a relatively reliable one - for a multi-part NOTAM is the infamous Sydney crane list, at time of writing in NOTAM H6002/18, which at the moment comes in three parts and has the part listing in field A):

> H6002/18 NOTAMR H5974/18
>   Q) YMMM/QOBCE/IV/M/AE/000/999/3357S15111E008
>   A) YSSY PART 1 OF 3
>   B) 1811190334 
>   C) 1811300500 EST
>   E) OBSTACLE CRANES AT FLW LOCATIONS
>  
>   239FT AMSL BRG 002 MAG 1.58NM FM ARP
>   497FT AMSL BRG 002 MAG 3.82NM FM ARP
>   220FT AMSL BRG 002 MAG 1.38NM FM ARP OBST UNLIT
>   413FT AMSL BRG 003 MAG 3.09NM FM ARP
>   410FT AMSL BRG 003 MAG 3.14NM FM ARP
>   577FT AMSL BRG 003 MAG 4.65NM FM ARP
>   685FT AMSL BRG 004 MAG 4.26NM FM ARP
>   249FT AMSL BRG 004 MAG 2.98NM FM ARP
>   413FT AMSL BRG 004 MAG 3.18NM FM ARP
>   224FT AMSL BRG 005 MAG 1.53NM FM ARP OBST UNLIT
>   500FT AMSL BRG 005 MAG 3.42NM FM ARP
>   953FT AMSL BRG 005 MAG 5.26NM FM ARP
>   623FT AMSL BRG 006 MAG 4.54NM FM ARP
>   PART 1 OF 3

Found at [FAA pilot briefing site](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&reportType=RAW&formatType=DOMESTIC&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs&retrieveLocId=YSSY).

Comment: Also an example of the nigh-incomprehensibility of NOTAMs.

Comment: As a railroad person who's seen many a hard-to-read train order, I recognize I'm looking at an extreme case, but still.  That would never pass muster on rail: firstly the topic would be an Order or Notice in full page format. But even as a train order, it would require deployment of a technology (invented by George Westinghouse) called the "carriage return" or "newline".  I am unable to demonstrate here in a comment.

Comment: To be fair, everywhere I‘ve seen this NOTAM, the carriage returns were in the right places. I couldn’t get them to work in the quote on the iPhone app, though.

Comment: The standard [US stadium security NOTAM](https://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_7_4319.html) is three parts too. Greece and Turkey [like to carry on an entire diplomatic spat in the NOTAM database](https://ops.group/blog/the-annual-greece-v-turkey-notam-battle/). The NTSB chair recently called the system ["messed up" and "garbage"](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/business-aviation/2018-09-28/ntsb-chairman-calls-notams-garbage) thanks to this kind of nonsense.

Comment: Now that carriage returns are live, it's more comprehensible, but not much.

Comment: For next time, you can enter "newlines" with "<space><space><enter>"